# Find lowest common hypernym given multiple words in WordsNet (Python)

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet, hypernym

If I have a list of words in python such as:

```
words = ["blue", "red", "ball"]
```

Is there a way to programmatically produce the hypernyms for this group of words using WordNet?

Comment: The short answer is yes, the exact answer depends on your parameters. Say for two words, there is the [lowest_common_hypernyms](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet_lch.html) function but [it has had some problems historically](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/395). For a list of words, [it gets more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605807/nltk-wordnet-synset-for-word-phrase). So I'd read those, try them out and include the code in this to show what you are really trying to do and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29478711/610569 to note the difference between "sense" (synset/concept) vs "words" (in the context of wordnet, lemmas).

Given two synsets (**NOT words**), it is possible to find the lowest common hypernym between them:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# A word can represent multiple meaning (aka synsets)
>>> wn.synsets('dog')
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n.01'), Synset('frank.n.02'), Synset('pawl.n.01'), Synset('andiron.n.01'), Synset('chase.v.01')]

>>> wn.synsets('cat')
[Synset('cat.n.01'), Synset('guy.n.01'), Synset('cat.n.03'), Synset('kat.n.01'), Synset('cat-o'-nine-tails.n.01'), Synset('caterpillar.n.02'), Synset('big_cat.n.01'), Synset('computerized_tomography.n.01'), Synset('cat.v.01'), Synset('vomit.v.01')]

>>> wn.synsets('dog')[0].definition()
u'a member of the genus Canis (probably descended from the common wolf) that has been domesticated by man since prehistoric times; occurs in many breeds'

>>> wn.synsets('cat')[0].definition()
u'feline mammal usually having thick soft fur and no ability to roar: domestic cats; wildcats'

>>> dog = wn.synsets('dog')[0]
>>> cat = wn.synsets('cat')[0]


>>> cat.lowest_common_hypernyms(dog)
[Synset('carnivore.n.01')]
```

See http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet_lch.html

**Is lowest common hypernyms reliable?**

Wordnet is a hand-crafted resource, so how reliable it depends on why and how the synset was created among the whole WordNet ontology

**Can I use this information for my NLP task?**

Perhaps... But most probably, it's not useful.

**Can it compare more than 2 synsets?**

Not exactly. You have to do multiple pairwise search, e.g.

```
>>> mouse = wn.synsets('mouse')[0]
>>> cat = wn.synsets('cat')[0]
>>> dog = wn.synsets('dog')[0]

>>> dog.lowest_common_hypernyms(cat)
[Synset('carnivore.n.01')]
>>> cat.lowest_common_hypernyms(mouse)
[Synset('placental.n.01')]
>>> dog.lowest_common_hypernyms(mouse)
[Synset('placental.n.01')]

>>> placental = dog.lowest_common_hypernyms(mouse)[0]
>>> carnivore = dog.lowest_common_hypernyms(cat)[0]
>>> placental.lowest_common_hypernyms(carnivore)
[Synset('placental.n.01')]
```

But you can see how inefficient it is. So it's easier if you rewrite your own code to traverse the WordNet ontology and find the lowest common hypernym given N no. of synsets instead of doing it pairwise.